# Is there any alternative of Refit to support sync methods

Tags: refit

since I have a project in which I am not using Async, I have searched about Refit alternative for Synchronous type-safe RestApi call but not found anything
please anyone can give any idea or suggestion which one I can use.

Comment: Did you had a chance to find solution?

Comment: Why would you not just await calls?